# DevExpress - How to disable editing of one cell if another cell has value

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, devexpress

My problem is the following: I have a DevExpress dataGrid where there are several rows, among them there is one called Variety and another VarietySupposed. My problem is that I cannot block the editing and even the access (the tabular does not pass inside the cell) of this cell called Variety Assumed when there is a value within Variety.

I have managed to get to the point where I have to change the editing property of the cell and I even get the object of the cell to change (code below) but I can't find a way to block that cell.

**JS Code:**

```
onRowPrepared: function (e) { 
    var dataGrid = e.component;  
    var rowIndex = dataGrid.getRowIndexByKey(e.key);  
    if (e.data !== undefined) {                      
        if(e.data.Id_Variedad != undefined && e.data.Id_Variedad !=null)
        {                              
            var this5 = dataGrid.getCellElement(rowIndex, 'VariedadSupuesta');                       
        }
    }
},
```

**View of the GRID:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r72l4.png

[image]